# Relation between Extensions and self-Extensions!

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, modules, homological-algebra, derived-functors

This should be considered as very general question regarding the extension group $Ext^i _A (R,S)$, in particular where $i=1$, for $R$ and $S$, a pair of given objects in an abelian category $A$. For the sake of concreteness, let's assume modules over an associative finite dimensional algebra A, over an algebraically closed field $K$ (if this setting possibly helps to address the question).

I wish to know under which additional assumptions on the setting (possibly the weakest set of them), we could derive information about $Ext^1 _A (R,S)$ from the self-extensions $Ext^1 _A (R,R)$ and $Ext^1 _A (S,S)$ and **the missing part**.

It is clear to me that in the current setting, there is not much one could say just based on the latter extension groups. But, my question is exactly about **the missing part** of this puzzle.

Knowing about $Hom _A (R,S)$ seems to strong to me. I know that having $Ext^i _A$ as derived functors from $Hom _A $ might make it impossible to say something very useful, but many questions seem stupid at the beginning (if not at the end either)!

Comment: Flat base change, maybe?

Comment: @Andy Any elaboration on your comment or the motivation behind your guess?

Comment: Turns out I didn't really pay attention while I was reading and I didn't notice you're working always in $A$-mod, I don't really know why I thought you were changing basis somewhere. At this point I don't know what I had in mind. But then again, the Dold-Kan correspondence should give you a lot more structure (simplicial objects) to work with and maybe do something useful.